# Inconsistencies in MS Access Query when using DateAdd

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

first off thank you for reading my post. I am trying to perform a computation in Access. Basically, I have jobs which last a variable amount of time and generate revenue.

Most of the computations are correct ~90%, but I'm finding random inconsistencies and I can't figure out what I am doing incorrectly.

I am trying to create queries for each month to show the amount of revenue generated for each job. I am taking `total amount of revenue / length of job` in order to compute the average monthly revenue.

I want the revenue to begin in the next calendar month (regardless of which day the job starts in the month)

For example, if I have a $100 job that begins on 2/28/16 and it is 4 months in duration, I want March, April, May and June to each have $25 for revenue.

Here are the issues I am seeing in the results:

1. When a job begins on 1/1/2016, the query is beginning revenue for January, however I wanted it to show revenue beginning February
2. I see an instance where a job begins on 2/26/2016 and is to be 3 months long, however, the query is only showing revenue for March and April when it should be showing it for March, April and May.

Is there something that stands out that I am incorrectly doing? Thanks in advance, I've been stuck on this and could use the help :)

Here is the query for the June month. I have a query for each month.

```
  IIf(#6/1/2016#>=DateAdd("m",0,[Start Date]) 
 And #6/30/2016#<=DateAdd("m",[Job Length] + 1),
 [Total $]/ [Job Length],0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax for the second DateAdd is incomplete, so try:

```
IIf([Start Date]<=#6/1/2016# And DateAdd("m",[Job Length] + 1,[Start Date])>=#6/30/2016#,[Total $]/[Job Length],0)
```